# Why PHP definitions in PHP-DI not working?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

I try to inject dependencies in my handler (service) in my project

```
class App
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->di();
    }

    public function di() {
        $containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder;
        $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
            RegionSql::class => create(App\Connections\MySqlConnection::class),
            CreateRegionHandler::class => create(Region\Infrastructure\Persistance\RegionSql::class),
        ]);
        $container = $containerBuilder->build();
        return $container;
    }
}
```

My Handler

```
class CreateRegionHandler
{
    private RegionRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(RegionRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
```

`RegionRepository` - an interface, `RegionSQL` is implementation

I trying to run a handler with something like commandBus

`$this->commandBus->execute(new CreateRegionCommand('address', 'postal_code', 'country'));`

CommandBus

```
  public function execute($command)
    {
        $handler = $this->resolveHandler($command);
        call_user_func_array([$handler, 'handle'], [$command]);
    }

    private function resolveHandler($command)
    {
        $handler_class = substr(get_class($command), 0, -7) . 'Handler';
        $run = new \ReflectionClass($handler_class);
        return $run->newInstance();
    }
```

But i getting an error
`Too few arguments to function Region\Application\Command\CreateRegionHandler::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in Region\Application\Command\CreateRegionHandler.php:`

How to get `$repository` in my `CreateRegionHandler`? 
I tried `CreateRegionHandler::class => autowire(Region\Infrastructure\Persistance\RegionSql::class)` but it doesn't work too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating the Container in the `App` class, but you are not using it then.

PHP-DI will not magically intercept class creations. You have to use `$container->get(<class name>)` instead of `$run->newInstance()`.

See [the documentation](https://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html#3-create-the-objects) for more details.